# List of all webrequests in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im playing around with making my first chrome extension. Im making a small extension that monitors the webrequests a page makes. This means that im listening to the: chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener event

I am a little confused on how to execute this code on every page i load. It works on any page if i open the extension web page and run the code in this context. However i would like it to run regardless of having the page open. How do i go around doing this?

I looked at content_scripts, but havent figured out if they are the proper path to take - and ven if they are how do i send a message from my content script to my web page notifying it to run the code. As far as i understand this the content script is first run after the page has been loaded and therefore it does not matter if i call my page and add the listeners, because the show is already over - is this correct?

The wa i understand this is that i cannot add listeners in the content script - hence the need to make this messaging thing - is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put the `onBeforeRequest` listener in a [`background page`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), specifically the persistent variant of it. When the event is invoked, whatever you have in the handler will be run.

Comment: Getting an error saying that i cannot use the webRequest from event pages: http://screencast.com/t/0vEMR7tt3o6s

Comment: @BrianHvarregaard Then change it to a persistent background page by either removing the `"persistent": false` or changing it to true. It is supposed to work with event handlers, but I guess it doesn't with these.